# using jquery to set class to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got the following Html:

```
<ul class="specs">
        <li>
            <div class="trigger">› City (2)</div>
            <div class="cityByLocation">
                <ul>
                    <li class="cityInfo">
                        <div class="cityName" style="float: left;">
                            › New York
                        </div>
                        <div class="cityDistance" style="float: left;">
                            430 miles
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-take"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cityInfo">
                        <div class="cityName" style="float: left;">
                            › Chicago
                        </div>
                        <div class="cityDistance" style="float: left;">
                            430 miles
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-take"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
<ul>
```

When i click on "City (2)", both divs under appear. However, i would like to add a class to them.

This is my js right now:

```
$('.trigger').click(function ()
    {
        $(this).siblings('div').eq($(this).index()).toggle();

        $(this).eq($(this).index()).toggleClass("locationSelected");

        return false;
    });
```

This adds a blue background behind the name "City (2)", but not the underlying divs, which i want.

Its the div with class "cityByLocation" i would like to add the class locationSelected to.

Edit:

I ended up using

> $('.trigger').click(function () {
>       $(this).siblings('div').eq($(this).index()).toggle();
>       $(this).toggleClass("locationSelected");
>       $(this).siblings('div').eq($(this).index()).toggleClass("locationSelected");
>
> ```
> return false; });
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't $(this).eq($(this).index()) be the same as $(this)?

Comment: It seems you're right. I'm so confused with jquery selecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using `toggleClass`, use `addClass`

```
$(this).eq($(this).index()).addClass("locationSelected");
```

Comment: +1'd for a correct answer in context of the OP's code, but correct me if I'm wrong...  $(this).eq($(this).index()) ===  $(this)

Comment: $(this).addClass("locationSelected");  makes more sense here

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).siblings('.cityByLocation').addClass("locationSelected");
```

Use that if you only want to add the class, but use `toggleClass` instead if you want to remove it on alternating clicks.

Comment: This seems closest to the answers, but it still won't work. I've tried exactly this before. Any other ideas?

Comment: This worked. The floating in my divs made it seem like it didn't at first.

Comment: I can't seem to keep the li "cityInfo" at one line. Any ideas if i can't float them?

Comment: You can, but you have to give them explicit widths. If still in doubt, you can ask a separate question about that (it would be off topic to extend this discussion here).

Comment: Done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569589/i-got-some-ul-li-height-problems

Answer (score 0):

```
.addClass("locationSelected");
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, on the assumption you want to add the class-names to the `div` elements nested within the neighbouring `div` and `ul`:

```
$(this).next('.cityByLocation').find('div').addClass('locationSelected');
```