# i got some ul li height problems

Tags: html, css

When inspecting my elements, i noticed my height on the first li is very low.

I'm trying to add a background to the whole li after selecting the "city (2)".

The background fills only City(2) an half of New York. I tried without floating, but then i can't get them lined up.

I've added 2 photos. One where i have floating, and one without.

[image: With floating]

[image: Without floating]

```
<ul class="specs">
        <li>
            <div class="trigger">› City (2)</div>
            <div class="cityByLocation">
                <ul>
                    <li class="cityInfo">
                        <div class="cityName" style="float: left;">
                            › New York
                        </div>
                        <div class="cityDistance" style="float: left;">
                            430 miles
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-take"></div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="cityInfo">
                        <div class="cityName" style="float: left;">
                            › Chicago
                        </div>
                        <div class="cityDistance" style="float: left;">
                            430 miles
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-take"></div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
<ul>
```

css:

```
.cityName{
    float: left;
    width: 45%;
}


.cityDistance {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}

.specs {

    padding: 0;
}

.specs li {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;

    list-style: none;
}

.specs ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's the precise layout you're trying to achieve, but I guess you should be floating the list items (`.cityInfo`), not the city names and locations.

Comment: I'm trying to make it look like the first picture, but with background all the way down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear your floats as Eric said. The simplest way to achieve that is by applying `overflow: hidden` to the container, so:

```
.cityByLocation {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a3GLG/

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem.

The problem happens when a floated element is within a container box, that element does not automatically force the container’s height adjust to the floated element. When an element is floated, its parent no longer contains it because the float is removed from the flow.

You can use 2 methods to fix it:

{clear:both} or .clearfix

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

[source](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)

Comment: Where should i add it in the html then?

Comment: add the code to your css, then add the class 'clearfix' to your floated elements. If you can, recreate the problem in [jsFiddle.](http://www.jsfiddle.com) It will help me better assist you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also fix it by setting `overflow: hidden` to `li` element. It will clear and auto calculate height.

-- update --

thanks @mickmackusa

https://jsfiddle.net/e94pzbbn/1/

Comment: To improve the value of your answer, you might setup a runnable script on this page or provide a link to an external demonstration.